# Why does AssertRaises persist a reference to an object beyond the scope of the test function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bit of code that checks an attribute to make sure that it can be converted to an integer. It does this by adding a try/except block and then raising a more informative exception. However, when I check the exception in my test with AssertRaises, the destructor for the object is not called! I can't figure out how a reference to the object is surviving beyond the scope of the test function. Does anyone know what's happening behind the scenes to make this happen?

Here's my code stripped down to just the failure:

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self):
        print("initing")
    def __del__(self):
        print("deleting")
    def f(self, val):
        try:
            int(val)
        except:
            raise Exception("what?")

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_dummy(self):
        print("Starting test")
        d = Dummy()
        self.assertRaisesRegex(Exception,
            "what?",
            d.f,
            'one',
            )
        print("Ending test")
```

And here is the test output:

```
Starting test
initing
Ending test
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 0.001s
```

Notice it does not print 'deleting'

This only happens when I raise an exception in the exception block of my function. If I use an if/else and raise the exception, this does not happen.

This also happens when using regular old AssertRaises, and it happens when using AssertRaises as a context.